# Install Mediapipe for Raspberry Pi 2B

Tags: pi-2

I'm a high schooler looking to use the `cvzone` module, which requires `mediapipe`, for my project. However, I'm getting errors in importing and I wanted to know if it is even possible to download `mediapipe` onto a Raspberry Pi 2. If so, then what's the process necessary?

The specific error is:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/catapult.py", line 5, in <module>
    from cvzone.PoseModule import PoseDetector
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cvzone/PoseModule.py", line 7, in <module>
    import mediapipe as mp
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mediapipe'
```

Comment: They are both python modules. When trying to use cvzone, I get an error saying module mediapipe is not found. And trying to install mediapipe brings a ModuleNotFoundError. I'm using 10 (buster).

Comment: Exactly how are you trying to install these modules. Pls add output of install procedure to your question

Comment: I've installed opencv, but when I try to install mediapipe using pip, or in thonny IDE, it results in the same error: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mediapipe (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for mediapipe.

Comment: Include the exact `pip` command in your question, and put the distro name in the question too.